# Configure application settings for Azure Static Web Apps (React MSAL)

Tags: reactjs, config, app-config, azure-ad-msal, azure-static-web-app

I'm learning about MSAL authentication in React application per environment.

authConfig.ts

```
import { Configuration } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { envConfig } from "./config";

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: envConfig.msalConfig.uiClientId,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${envConfig.msalConfig.tenantId}`,
        redirectUri: "/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/"
    }
};

// scopes
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: envConfig.msalConfig.scopes
  };

// endpoints 
export const config = {
    endpoint: `${envConfig.msalConfig.serviceBaseUrl}/api/v1/items`
};
```

IEnvConfig:

```
export interface IEnvConfig {  
  env: string;
  msalConfig: {
    uiClientId: string;
    authority: string;
    apiClientId: string;
    tenantId: string;
    serviceBaseUrl: string;
    scopes: string[];
  };
}
```

prod.ts

```
import { IEnvConfig } from "../config";

export const prod: IEnvConfig = {  
  env: "PROD",
  msalConfig: {
    uiClientId: "",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    apiClientId: "",
    tenantId: "tenantId",
    serviceBaseUrl: "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net",
    scopes: []
  },

};
```

INT

```
export const int: IEnvConfig = {  
  env: "INT",
  msalConfig: {
    uiClientId: "",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    apiClientId: "",
    tenantId: "tenantId",
    serviceBaseUrl: "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net",
    scopes: []
  },
};
```

UA:

```
export const ua: IEnvConfig = {  
  env: "UA",
  msalConfig: {
    uiClientId: "",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    apiClientId: "",
    tenantId: "tenantId",
    serviceBaseUrl: "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net",
    scopes: []
  },
};
```

How do I select the config values based on environment? How do I check which environment I’m in?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring one object per env (`ua, int, prod`, etc) you should use only 1 global object (I.e. `config`) and set its values during build. Take a look to [Customizing Environment Variables for Arbitrary Build Environments](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) and [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for more information.